# showing local username instead of system name in remote desktop connection on server 2008 r2

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, remote-desktop, windows

I need to do a little customization in network.

I have a server 2008R2, placed in another network, can have multiple sessions.
Multiple users access it at the same time and resolving the actual user from the name of system become tough every time.
**Sessions can be active whether user is still connected or not.**
So the scenario is:

```
Two systems PC1 & PC2 and a server S1
Two users U1 and U2

U1 connects to S1 from PC1 then U2 from PC2
Now U2 wants to perform any server/system related operation 
     on S1 so he needs to inform another user
but when he goes to task manager to see active sessions he finds that 
**someone** has connected to S1 through PC1 (but not the exact username)
and if U1 has been disconnected U2 needs to find manually who is using PC1.

Management becomes more complex when user increases.
```

**I can not also rename PC1 to reflect U1 as U1 might be temporary account.**

Is it possible to hold dual identification in local dns server or any other way to map system to username?
It will be great if it is possible for any remote app service.

Comment: Are PC1 & PC2 shared computers used by multiple users or personal ones?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you see **someone** in Task Manager on S1 is most likely because the user used local shared account on S1 to log in to S1.

Client name will remain the same all the time, as long as you use the same machine. On the other hand, username may vary and this can either be personal domain account in your domain or local shared account on S1.

If PC1 and PC2 are shared computers, - ensure that each user who logs in to S1 uses domain account, or at least personal distinguished local account on S1 - this will resolve an issue with not knows users in Task Manager/Users.